# Строго ограничить время скрипта PHP

Tags: php, cron

Скрипт выполняется по крону, что-то тащит из интернета, куда-то пишет, кому-то отдаёт. Передо мной стоит проблема запуска дубликата, который не должен запускаться, причём сам скрипт должен завершить свою работу перед запуском нового.
Что я пробовал:

1. max_execution_time();
2. set_time_limit();
3. Использовать while(date('s', time()) < 57);
4. Использовать создание блокирующего запуск файла и проверять его наличие.

Ничего из вышеперечисленных методов не привело к желаемому результату. Что посоветуете сделать в моей ситуации?

Comment: запускайте кроном не сам скрипт, а баш скрипт. В баш скрипте проверяйте существующий процесс php. Если он висит, то ничего не делайте до следующего запуска крона

Comment: VPS хостинг, доступа к SSH нет, exec и shell_exec отключены

Comment: @АртёмАндреев у VPS всегда строго обязательно есть SSH и полный доступ, без исключений. Видимо, вы путаете VPS с чем-то другим

Comment: @andreymal, да, вы правы, я ошибся. Shared.

Answer (score 1):

В подобной ситуации использовали запись в файл метки о том что скрипт работает.
И когда скрипт запускается еще раз, то смотри на метку.